# Sorted a list by frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I would like to sort a list by its frequency in descending order. If the frequency for two values is the same, then I also want the descending order for these two values.

For example,

```
mylist = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

I would like my result to be

```
[4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,2,2,2,1,1].
```

If I use

```
sorted(mylist,key = mylist.count,reverse = True)
```

I would get

```
[4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,5,5,5,1,1];
```

I tried

```
 sorted(mylist,key = lambda x:(mylist.count,-x),reverse = True)
```

But I think something is wrong, and it only give me the result:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5].
```

So my questions are how can I get the result I want and why the result will be

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

if I use

```
sorted(mylist,key = lambda x:(mylist.count,-x),reverse = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Counter to get the frequencies, then sort by the frequencies it gives:

```py
from collections import Counter

def sorted_by_frequency(arr):
    counts = Counter(arr)

    # secondarily sort by value
    arr2 = sorted(arr, reverse=True)

    # primarily sort by frequency
    return sorted(arr2, key=counts.get, reverse=True)

# Usage:
>>> sorted_by_frequency([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(mylist)
new_list = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: (counts[x], x), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: (mylist.count, -x), reverse=True)
```

go wrong?

It compares the keys, so for example the two values `3` and `1` become the pairs `(mylist.count, -3)` and `(mylist.count, -1)` and the comparison would be `(mylist.count, -3) < (mylist.count, -1)`.

So the *obvious* mistake is that the pairs don't have the *frequencies* of the numbers as intended. Instead they have that *function*. And the function is not less than itself.

But I find it interesting to note what exactly happens then. How does that pair comparison work? You might think that `(a, b) < (c, d)` is equivalent to `(a < c) or (a == c and b < d)`. That is not the case. Because that would evaluate `mylist.count < mylist.count`, and then you'd crash with a `TypeError`. The actual way tuples compare with each other is by [first finding a difference](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8e1dd55e63d18d40e78d941fc9233d2c77bcd3de/Objects/tupleobject.c#L696-L707), and that's done by checking *equality*. And `mylist.count == mylist.count` not only doesn't crash but returns `True`. So the tuple comparison then goes to the next index, where it will find the `-3` and `-1`.

So essentially you're really only doing

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: -x, reverse=True)
```

and the negation and the `reverse=True` cancel each other out, so you get the same as

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: x)
```

or just

```
sorted(mylist)
```

Now how to get it right? One way is to *call* the function (and to remove the negation):

```
result = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: (mylist.count(x), x), reverse=True)
```

Or negate both frequency and value, instead of `reverse=True`:

```
result = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: (-mylist.count(x), -x))
```

Another would be to take advantage of the sort's stability and use two simpler sorts (which might even be faster than the one more elaborate sort):

```
result = sorted(mylist, reverse=True)
result.sort(key=mylist.count, reverse=True)
```

Note that here we *don't* have to call `mylist.count` ourselves, because as it is the key it will be called for us. Just like your "lambda function" does get called (just not the function inside its result). Also note that I use `sorted` followed by in-place `sort` - no point creating yet another list and incur the costs associated with that.

Though in all cases, for long lists it would be more efficient to use a `collections.Counter` instead of `mylist.count`, as the latter makes the solution take O(n<sup>2</sup>) instead of O(n log n).